# Creating a proxy instance failed - why this error on Windows server 2012, IIS8 using NHibernate 1.2 and Castle.DynamicProxy 1.1.5?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, nhibernate, visual-studio-2008

My company needs to move several web sites from a Windows 2008 server to a Windows 2012 server. Databases: SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012.

A web site that uses NHibernate 1.2.0.4000 and Castle.DynamicProxy 1.1.5.0 has worked perfectly for a long time. Application Pool set to .NET Framework v2.0 og Classic Mode. On the new server we get this error at first attempt to create a persistent object:

> Application_Error: UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko - Name: InternetExplorer - Version: 11.0 - UserHostAddress: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder._TermCreateClass(Int32 handle, Module module)
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Builder.CodeBuilder.AbstractEasyType.BuildType()
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Builder.CodeBuilder.AbstractEasyType.BuildType()
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Builder.CodeGenerators.BaseCodeGenerator.CreateType()
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Builder.CodeGenerators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateCode(Type baseClass, Type[] interfaces)
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.Builder.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxy(Type theClass, Type[] interfaces)
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type baseClass, Type[] interfaces, IInterceptor interceptor, Boolean checkAbstract, Object[] argumentsForConstructor)
>   at NHibernate.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
>
> Message: Creating a proxy instance failed- Source: NKU.Model- TargetSite: System.Object Get(System.Type, System.Object)-
>   StackTrace:
>   at NKU.Model.VZBaseDataAccess.Get(Type type, Object id) in C:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\NKU.Model\NKU.Model\VZBaseDataAccess.cs:line 181
>   at ASP.global_asax.Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\NKUWeb\Global.asax:line 113
>   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.RaiseOnStart(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState()
>   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

For me the following thing worked:

In IIS go to your application pool and select the advanced settings. There you will find a feature (General) 'Enable 32-Bit Applications'. Choose 'True'.
Give a try.

Comment: Hey Pilsz. Sorry it took me so long to answer. Now I have tried your solution on the first website and I can open it. I will try some more during this weekend and return. The other solution I have tried is to upgrade to a newer version of both the .net framework and Nhibernate and that worked too but demanded a lot of updates in the Hhibernate hql code. Thanks!!